# How to fix page error 500 when SQL query takes too long?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I recently upgraded my cloud instance from Ubuntu 14 to 16. It's a Laravel application, there's a page which reads about 200000 entries from a table with 3 columns and writes them to a CSV file. The query involves 2 where clauses- `status=0` and `CHAR_LENGTH()=7`.This is the query-

`select code from code where status=0 and CHAR_LENGTH(code)=7 limit 200000;`

There are more than 30 million entries in that code table.

The page had been working before upgrading to Ubuntu 16, but now the page gives Error 500 after being stuck on the page for about 1-2 minutes.
Note that the page works if I try to read lower number of entries e.g. 20 entries and the file also gets written.

Can anyone please help me with this it's a critical operation for our website.

Comment: the best bet would be to optimise the query - which we can't help you with, since you didn't share any **code**. please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully, then *edit* your question to include all necessary information.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I just edited the question could you please give me some more insight?

Comment: please include a **complete** code sample that's able to reproduce your problem. that includes the php-code where you write the CSV. and take care of proper formatting.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you got this error after **only** upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to 18? Did anything else change? Did the database size increase? Did you change DB structure/remove indices? Did you change your database server/application server instance? Anything else?

Comment: After the upgrade the PHP version changed from 5 to 7.2. Didn't change anything else everything remains the same. @Sumit

Comment: Will it read first 200000 every time ? If yes , use limit 1, 200000 or use limit $start, 200000 and also in the PHP settings change max_input_time = 3000 (max) , memory_limit = -1 and also increase post_max_size value according to your server configuration .

Comment: How do you run the application as cli or via http request? Did you check php or apache/nginx (what is used) error logs? Possible errors are timeout, permissions, memory. So please provide the details.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the problem, after the upgrade the PHP5 folder was deleted and PHP 7 was installed. Previously in php5/fpm/php.ini file the max_execution_time and memory_limit was set to 600 and 2GB respectively. But after the upgrade in php/7/fpm/php.ini file the default values for max_execution_time and memory_limit was set to 60 and 300MB respectively. 
I changed the values to 600 and 2GB and now the system is working perfectly.